# My apk showing "Your device is not compatible with this version", while installing from web and play store

Tags: android

Yesterday I uploaded two apk on play store, now both are live on play store, but when I download, one of them is showing your device is not compatible with this version. Please help me, here is my manifiest file:

```
    defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}

<permission
    android:name="com.techie.smart.smarttechie.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.tracksafeapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="false" />


<application
    android:name="android.app.Application"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyALqQ_WMoOX-qddSQF6QPXBa12sV2yAfVQ" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".main.RegistrationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".main.MapActivity3" />
    <activity android:name=".main.MapActivity2" />
    <activity android:name=".ChildActivities.CategoryActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChildActivities.SubCategoryActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChildActivities.DepthCategoryActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChildActivities.ShopActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChildActivities.ProductActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".test.Test"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main.ForgotPassword"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main.ChangePassword"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_change_password"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".main.BookDeliverymanActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to remove these...From Mainfest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.camera" /> //Remove this
```

> Also Remove this..

```
 defaultConfig {
  multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

Used this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
```

Instead of

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"  android:required="false" />
```

> And Also add this feature also

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

> And also add these to mainfest

```
 <supports-screens
  android:largeScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:xlargeScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>
```

> Also android:glEsVersion not inside the application

```
   <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Note: if all permission needed in your project than remain if anyone not use than remove it.

Comment: That is not how quotes are supposed to be used.

Comment: @JoxTraex
I am seeing these links have quotes problem showing incompatile to all device mean to 0 

like these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822676/android-app-compatible-with-0-devices
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589061/google-play-zero-supported-devices and many occurs this problem..

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with:

```
<uses-feature
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
     android:required="true" />
```

### As mentioned in documention

> Adding this declaration causes Google Play to restrict your
>   application from being installed on devices that do not support OpenGL
>   ES 2.0.